Where to specify git config in VSCode bash?
Issue:
When using any commands starting with git I get the following error. Happens specifically for Bash run in VSCode, but not elsewhere.
E.g.:
$ git
fatal: unable to access 'C:\Users?MJSS/.config/git/config': Invalid argument

Guess:
My guess is that it has something to do with one of shellIntegration .sh or .zsh files for VSCode (e.g. shellIntegration-bash.sh). On my computer, they are stored in the following path:
"*C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\workbench\contrib\terminal\browser\media*"
Additional info:

Run Windows
Have reinstalled Git and GitBash
Have reinstalled VSCode
Works in GitBash outside of VSCode
Works in Cmd Prompt in VSCode
VSCode has a status message on the bash terminal (seen below):



what is this Users?MJSS question mark

If you think it has to do with shellIntegration-bash.sh ... well what is the contents of that file?

makes you wonder if \E is being interpreted as some kind of escape but not sure. Window path separators may not be playing well here (although in general I wouldn't say VSCode ordinarily has problems on windows with git or gitbash)

Maybe duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/78509931/6330106.

Solution was unrelated to multiple environments, contents of .gitconfig .bashrc or related, which I first assumed. Re-installing vscode, gitbash and git did not solve the issue.
Rather the automatically generated content in C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\workbench\contrib\terminal\browser\media\ seemed to for some reason not provide an escape for a backslash in one of the path settings.
Deleting the content of this folder solved the issue.
